# RadMaskedTextBox ssn format

Tags: css, asp.net, internet-explorer, telerik

I have a RadMaskedTextBox for SSN while entering value in it, the first two characters are clearing up itself and getting RegularExpressionValidator message. Can some body help me in this.This problem exits in IE browsers only.

```
 <span id="SSN" runat="server">*</span>Social Security Number</label>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="TaxId_RegEx" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="TaxId"
            Display="None" ValidationExpression="^\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}$" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid 9 digit SSN."  Enabled="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TaxId_ReqField"
 runat="server" ControlToValidate="TaxId"
            Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter a value for this required field."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <radI:RadMaskedTextBox CssClass="box_SSN" SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll" ID="TaxId"
            Width="85px" Mask="###-##-####" runat="server">
        </radI:RadMaskedTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$
```

Instead of:

```
^\d{3}\-\d{2}\-\d{4}
```

This is working perfectly for me in IE:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator   
         ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"  
         runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Text="*">  
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator   
        ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"  
        runat="server"   
        ValidationExpression="\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}"  
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1"  
        ErrorMessage="Input valid SSN!">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>  

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit"/>
```

Not sure why you have

> Display="None"

Comment: still the problem exists with ^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$